# Sharepoint Server search indexing phpBB. Removing sid parameter

Tags: 2010, search

I'm trying to index a phpBB board. Unfortunately the url always has an sid= parameter attached to it suggesting there is a problem with authentication.

I've tried setting both forms and cookie authentication via a crawl rule but with no joy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be a permissions issue if the bb is allowed to have anonymous access.  If you think it's an access issue, then create a read only user in phpbb and use those credentials as the user initiating the search on the content source.

My belief is the issue is that all the posts and comments are stored in the phpbb database and are the root of the problem.  Have you configured a crawl rule on this content source that includes the the option,  Crawl complex URLs (URLs that contain a question mark (?)) (based on 2007 server central admin, I don't have access to a 2010 CA at the moment).

Comment: Access is not the issue, the problem is my crawled urls are polluted with the sid (session id) parameter which contains a guid type value. This value will change each time the pages are crawled and so each crawl will consider all pages as completely new, which I assume will play havoc with any search alerts which return a phpBB result.